# Get Name of Theorem Environment From Label

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, theorems

I'm trying to create a command, say `envName`, with the following behaviour (where `theorem` and `lemma` are AMS Theorem environments):

```
\begin{theorem}\label{myThm}
    Lorem ipsum...
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
    In the statement of the \envName{myThm}...
\end{proof}
```

should give

> In the statement of the theorem...

in the `proof` environment, whereas

```
\begin{lemma}\label{myLemma}
    Lorem ipsum...
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
    In the statement of the \envName{myLemma}...
\end{proof}
```

should give

> In the statement of the lemma...

---

`\cref*` from the `cleveref` package will give me "Theorem 1.1" without a hyperlink for example, but I can't seem to find a way to get rid of the number. I'm also using the `capitalise` argument for `cleveref`, but don't want the environment names in `envName` capitalised.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `\namecref`?

Comment: Many thanks, `\lcnamecref` did exactly what I was looking for. I should have read the documentation more carefully, I didn't notice `namecref` when I was looking, I assumed it was `nameref`. If you'd like to post this as an answer I'd gladly accept it, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `cleveref` also define the command `\namecref` to typeset the ref name without numbers.

```
\begin{lemma}\label{myLemma}
    Lorem ipsum...
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
    In the statement of the \namecref{myLemma}...
\end{proof}
```